# iOS8: Separator zero and accessory view disclosure indicator

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've read about how to make the cell full width again in iOS 8 so the separator extends to the left edge.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

However after my view controller is loaded the disclosure indicator and the label left of it "jump" a little bit further left, which the user can see. I've set the constraints of the label to "Trailing space of label to Superview x". So why is there this jump? How can I avoid it? So annoying...I've also tried of setting the constraint not to the margin but relative to the view without the margin and the jump was still there